# Gallery blinks on notifydatasetchanged in Gallery BaseAdapter

Tags: android, gallery, baseadapter

I am new to Android. I am creating a gallery of webviews, there I have to show 200 webview content in the BaseAdapter. I do not want to load all the 200 webviews together. So on slide of the gallery I will add each webviews to BaseAdapter and will remove the shown webviews, then I will refresh the BaseAdapter with "notifydatasetchanged ()"

Here the issue Im facing is; when I update the BaseAdapter on "notifydatasetchanged()" the gallery gets refreshed, At the moment of refreshing the gallery get blinks. I want to remove the blinking on refreshing the BaseAdapter. Is it Possible ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I believe that is because you create the next view at runtime, you could try creating 3 at the time. previous, current, and next. You could also try to add this in activity manifest: android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: It is not working. The gallery is still blinks on update even if I am adding one after another by keeping previous views .

Comment: did you add the code in the manifest as well?

Answer (score 3):

I just corrected it in my app :)
I will try to explain with my legendary English.

`BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` calls `Adapter.getView(...)` for all displayed views.
So you just have to handle it in your Overridden method (in my case i put a business object in view.Tag)  :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // View is good to use
    if (convertView != null && convertView.getTag() != null && convertView.getTag() == getItem(position)){ 
        return convertView; 
    }else {
        //Do your stuff
        convertView.setTag(getItem(position))
        return convertView;
    }


}
```

I hope it will help someone even 3 years later :)